# Clicking on rendered text in pygame

Tags: python, user-controls, pygame

So I am trying to get "buttons" for my main menu. This isn't all of the code, but its the portion I think might be relevant. I've tested by printing statements/values, that when I push the button down, it is registering the mouse, and I know the rect of the text (In this case play_game_rect), so by following another thread I decided to assign the mouse.get_pos() to the variable mouse_position. I then tried collidepoint() and passing in the mouse_position variable. I feel like the collidepoint() is might be the correct method to do this. I also verified that mouse_position does contain the x,y value I desire. I think it's probably just a line or two to fix, but I am stuck.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if game_state == "Menu":
        #Create Button Text
        menu_main = headlines.render("Main Menu", True, WHITE)
        play_game = standard.render("Play Game", True, WHITE)
        instructions = standard.render("Instructions", True, WHITE)
        # Get Button Dimensions
        menu_main_rect = menu_main.get_rect()
        play_game_rect = play_game.get_rect()
        instructions_rect = instructions.get_rect()
        #Blit Buttons
        myWindow.blit(menu_main, (MENUX, MENUY))
        myWindow.blit(play_game, (MENUX, MENUY + 120))
        myWindow.blit(instructions, (MENUX, MENUY + 150))
        print play_game_rect
        if play_game_rect.collidepoint(mouse_position):
            game_state == "Game"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, having a closer look at this here:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect
will answer your question!

If not, here's the solution:

The rect you get with get_rect always has (0, 0) for the x and y value. When you blit the surfaces, however, you shift them but not the rect. Therefore the button rect is there (try to click somewhere in the top-left corner and see what happens) but not in the same position as the button image.

To solve this issue you have to shift the rect too:

```
play_game_rect = play_game.get_rect()
play_game_rect.x = MENUX
play_game_rect.y = MENUY
```

Do this for each of the buttons and it should work. If you didn't understand what the problem is, please ask again, this is an important issue you will encounter very often.

Comment: I did notice the readout of a 0 on x and y when printing my rect. For anyone following the example, I had to do play_game_rect.y = MENUY + 120 (as that was the actual play_game attritbute). Using your example it would trigger over my main menu text. Either way, this solved it, and by providing the location in the docs I'll spend a bit more time reading that section to make sure I really understand.I was reading the get_rect inside of font, and thinking that's the call I was making. Thanks a bunch! I was kind of starting to guess this might be an issue but I wasn't sure. Thanks

Comment: Of course, MENUY+120, I had overlooked that, sorry :) But the general approach is clear now, right? Otherwise feel free to ask, glad I could help!